# Parsing a specific text for values using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I would like to parse the below string using regular expressions to extract out the maxbit and minbit values. Could you please let me know how to do the same ?

```
MAXBIT     =>  87,  MINBIT =>  86,
```

EDIT 1: This was intended to be used in a python script. Thanks for Pwilcox for providing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming "MAXBIT" always precedes "MINBIT".  If so, you can use this regex (globally):

```
(?<=BIT\s*=>\s*)(\d+)
```

It basically says to find numbers that are preceded by "BIT", and then maybe some whitespace, and then "=>", and perhaps more whitespace.  The output would be an array of the maxbit and minbit values, respectively.

```js
let text = 'MAXBIT     =>  87,  MINBIT =>  86,'

let regex = /(?<=BIT\s*=>\s*)(\d+)/g;

let results = text.match(regex);

console.log({
  min: results[1],
  max: results[0]
});
```

If order is not always guaranteed, you may have to resort to two expressions:

```js
let text = 'MAXBIT     =>  87,  MINBIT =>  86,'

let regex = (prefix) => new RegExp(`(?<=${prefix}BIT\\s*=>\\s*)(\\d+)`, 'g');

let results = {
  min: text.match(regex('MIN'))[0],
  max: text.match(regex('MAX'))[0]
}

console.log(results);
```

---

**You asked for Python**

I gave it a shot as it's a future language I'd like to learn.  I discovered that variable length indicators aren't supported in lookbehinds, but they are supported in lookaheads.  So in order to make it work, you have to reverse the input string, the regex pattern, and the result.

```
import re # importing regex

text = 'MAXBIT     =>  87,  MINBIT =>  86,' 

text = text[::-1] # reverse it

minPattern = re.compile(r'\d+(?=\s*>=\s*TIBNIM)')
maxPattern = re.compile(r'\d+(?=\s*>=\s*TIBXAM)')

minBit = minPattern.search(text).group(0)[::-1]
maxBit = maxPattern.search(text).group(0)[::-1]

print(minBit)
print(maxBit)
```

Comment: Apologies. I should have probably mentioned that I wanted to use the regular expression in a python script. Would this work within python ?

Comment: I used javascript for the sake of the snippet and seeing it in action.  I don't know if it will work in Python but I did look up to make sure it supports lookbehind functionality, and it does.  So it's likely that this pattern would work.  Go ahead and test it out.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect python.  I also edited your question to add the python tag.  Hopefully it helps you.